# how to remove force close error in android emulator?

Tags: android-emulator

i have AMD Processor and 2 GB ram and i am using android 1.6 version.i have facing force close error in Android Emulator every time, how can i remove this error in emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a problem of the problem of the Processor and RAM.
You are facing the null error in the program code. at run time your program code will generate null error in Run-Time.